# Changes show in Edit Mode but not Object Mode

Tags: modeling

[image: mesh transform edits not showing in object mode]

In edit mode I achieved the left example through mesh > transform > to sphere. But in object mode the edits are not shown. How do I get my edits to stick for the purpose of 3D printing? @Chris

Comment: Suspect you're editing a shapekey rather than the base mesh.  Another option is a surface deform or corrective smooth modifier.

Comment: That's what the problem was. Under (Object Data Properties > Shape Keys) I had chosen KEY 1. When I chose BASIS instead my changes stuck when I switched to Object mode.  I can continue now but you mentioned 'surface deform' and 'corrective smooth modifier'. For my purpose of 3D printing, which of the 3 is the best option?

Comment: Neither.  I just meant either of those modifiers could lead to your edit mode changes failing to show up on your mesh.